# Regex to match word and substrings

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a list of commands a user can type into an HTML input element:

- create
- load
- update
- delete
- draw

Currently I am setting the pattern attribute equal to:

```
^([Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee]|[Ll][Oo][Aa][Dd]|[Uu][Pp][Dd][Aa][Tt][Ee]|[Dd][Ee][Ll][Ee][Tt][Ee]|[Dd][Rr][Aa][Ww])$
```

From what I have read, HTML5 cannot use the case insensitive regex flag, so I had to bracket every letter `[Cc]` to create a case insensitive pattern. If the user types a word that doesn't match a word in the list, a validation statement will notify them.

I do not want the validation statement to pop up if the user has typed a set of characters that *could* become a list item. For example, if the user were attempting to run the `create` command, I would want "c", "cr", "cre", "crea", "creat", and "create" to all be valid entries.

**How can I accomplish this with regex?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need a regular expression for that, you can use `some` method to loop throw an array of commands, and use `startsWith` method to check if there are any commands start with the input value, Also you can use `toLowerCase()` to ignore case sensitivity.

```js
const commands = ['create', 'load', 'update', 'delete', 'draw']
let prevInputValue = ''

const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const exist = commands.some(command => command.startsWith(value.toLowerCase()))
    
    if (!exist) {
        alert('Wrong Input');
        event.target.value = prevInputValue
    }
    prevInputValue = value;
})
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: As I understand it, `a` should not be valid, so using `command.startsWith(value)` would be the right way to go.

Comment: Yes, I think `startsWith` will be better than `includes` Updated, thanks.